# Python - how to change flask template when session variable change?

Tags: python, session, flask

Hi friend I want my template html file to display the loading spinner when session['train'] change. Here are the things I've tried but didn't work:

- The html file:

```html
<div class="messages">
    {% block content%}
    {% if session['training'] %}
      <div class="spinner"><div class="double-bounce1"></div>
      <div class="double-bounce2"><p style="font-weight:bold;font-size:16px;margin-left:-17px;color:white;">Training</p></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    {% else %}
      <div class="messages-content"></div>
    </div>
        <div class="message-box">
      <textarea type="text" class="message-input" placeholder="Type message..."></textarea>
      <button type="submit" class="message-submit">Send</button>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    {% endif %}
    {% endblock content%}
```

- Python Code:

```html
    def retrain():
        session['training']=True
    app = Flask(__name__)
    @app.route("/")
    def home():
        if session.get('logged_in'):
            return render_template('index.html')
        else:
            return render_template('login.html')
    @app.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
    def login():
        error = False
        POST_USERNAME = str(request.form['username'])
        POST_PASSWORD = str(request.form['password'])
        Session = sessionmaker(bind=enginedb)
        s = Session()
        query = s.query(User).filter(User.username.in_([POST_USERNAME]), User.password.in_([POST_PASSWORD]) )
        result = query.first()
        if result:
            session['logged_in'] = True ##for remember me function
            flash('Login success')
            return render_template('index.html')
        else:
            flash('Login failed!')
            return render_template('login.html',error=True) 
    @app.route("/logout")
    def logout(): 
        session['logged_in'] = False
        return home()
    @app.route('/message', methods=['POST'])
    def reply():
        answer=response(request.form['msg'])
        if "train" in answer:
               retrain()
        return jsonify( { 'text': answer})
```

The problem I'm encountering is that the spinner loader only display when I refresh my template page. I want whenever the variable "*answer*" in *reply()* contains "*train*", the template must auto reload and the spinner must be displayed!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are changing the session on the server in method `reply()`, but then returning json, and not returning anything that will cause the template to refresh or the session on the client to be updated.